# How to bind an object to an expression depending on other attribut in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular project with this variable :

```
$scope.kilometer = 20;
$scope.carType=1;
```

I would like that

```
$scope.priceperkilometer
```

equal

```
 10 if $scope.kilometer < 20 and $scope.carType=1
 20 if $scope.kilometer < 20 and $scope.carType=2
 30 if $scope.kilometer >= 20 and $scope.carType=1
 40 if $scope.kilometer >= 20 and $scope.carType=2
```

How to bind something like this?

Comment: what about using a function $scope.priceperkilometer=function(){} since that variable depends on other variables it makes more sence to do that.

Comment: yes. That what i'm start to think about. Do you thinks it will refresh the display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant with the function does work. But you also could pre-calculate the value (this might be faster if you use `priceperkilometer` often):

```
$scope.kilometer = 20;
$scope.carType = 1;

calculatePrice = function() {
    if ($scope.kilometer < 20 and $scope.carType=1)
        return 10;
    else if ($scope.kilometer < 20 and $scope.carType=2)
        return 20;
    else if ($scope.kilometer >= 20 and $scope.carType=1)
        return 30;
    else if ($scope.kilometer >= 20 and $scope.carType=2)
        return 40;
};

$scope.priceperkilometer = calculatePrice();

$scope.$watch('kilometer', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue)
        $scope.priceperkilometer = calculatePrice();
});

$scope.$watch('carType', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue)
        $scope.priceperkilometer = calculatePrice();
});
```